# Header Referer in Twitter OAuth

Tags: php, http, symfony2, oauth2

Есть проект на `symfony2`, там прикручена авторизация на `HWIOAuthBundle`.  После авторизации через twitter пользователя выкидывает на главную страницу сайта. Для возврата используется заголовок Referer.

VK и FB его отправляют, но TW ни в какую

Comment: Ю спик фром ёр харт?

Плиз, транслэйт зис инту рашн.

Comment: Есть проект на симфони2, там прикручена авторизация на hwi oauth bundle. Все как-бы работает, но вот беда, после авторизации через twitter пользователя выкидывает на главную страницу сайта.

Для возврата используется заголовок Referer. VK и FB его отправляют, но TW ни в какую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам с `HWIOAuthBundle` не сталкивался, но в [описании](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-configuring_resource_owners.md) есть параметр `use_referer`:

> Необязательный параметр для использования заголовка HTTP REFERER  в случае отсутствия предыдущий URL-адрес хранился в сеансе (т. е.  ресурс не был запрошен).

Думаю для твитера его надо ставить в состояние false

Comment: Да, спасибо. я разобрался уже. я смотрел исходники: Фаервол будет записывать в сессию обратный урл, а сам этот бандл будет поднимать это значение, если в ИХ параметрах указано use_referer: true (в двух местах)